# Multiple borders using CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to implement this design with just CSS, I couldn't find a way, do you guys have any idea?

- except using the lines as one image and implement it like `:before = "content"` which is not pure CSS

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with lines:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 5rem;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 2rem 5rem;
  color: gray;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box > span {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 25%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.box > span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
}
.box > span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 100%;
}
.box > span:nth-child(3):after {
  display: none;
}
.box > span:before, .box > span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  right: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.box > span:after {
  top: 100%;
}
.box:hover > span:before, .box:hover > span:after {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Solid
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot I tried but I couldn't fix as I wanted, they asked me to have 5 lines and on hover the line move down, would you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using gradients:

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 90%;
  top: 0;
  left: -15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 35.71%, grey 35.71%, grey 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 85.71%, grey 85.71%, grey 100%);
  background-size: 14.00px 14.00px;
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<button>Solid</button>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot I tried but I couldn't fix as I wanted, they asked me to have 5 lines and on hover the line move down, would you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Only idea i came up with for this would be using clip-path to force a shape into the element. As that would of course destroy any chance of applying a border, my attemt would be to fake a border with a parent container for the real button. I generated the Shape with this:

[Generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Thats definetly a lot of work for the effect and you will have to style active and hover pseudo-classes too to make it look good, but i think this is a way to do it.

```css
button {
  color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  /*Shape*/
  clip-path: polygon(15% 8%, 100% 8%, 100% 100%, 15% 100%, 15% 9%, 6% 1%, 6% 0);
  /*White or whatever your background color is when the button should look transparent*/
  background-color: white;
  /*Disable default border*/
  border: none;
  /*Center the Text a bit as we cut out width on the left of the real button*/
  padding-left: 15%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.fakedborder {
    /*Center button in the div so the fake border looks evenly*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*Make sure the button is in front*/
    z-index: 1;
    /*slightly bigger than the real button*/
    width: 302px;
    height: 92px;
    /*Same Shape!*/
    clip-path: polygon(15% 8%, 100% 8%, 100% 100%, 15% 100%, 15% 9%, 6% 1%, 6% 0);
    /*Color of the border you want*/
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="fakedborder"><button>TextisHere</button></div>
```